# How to fix this error message: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: codeigniter

There is this strange error when trying to login to admin page.

Try it:  http://www.masterlink.co.id/admin/

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/masterli/public_html/application/admin/models/Mpages.php on line 531
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '['

Filename: models/Mpages.php

Line Number: 531

Backtrace:

Line 531:

public function update_user()
    {

```
    $options = [
      'roles' => 'administrator',
    ];

    $hash = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $hash,
        'role' => $this->input->post('roles')       
    );      

    return $this->db->update('login', $data);

}
```

Line 531:  $options = [

How to fix the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your php version. Use [] not work in old php versions, change your code:

```
$options = array(
  'roles' => 'administrator',
);
```

Comment: see your homepage on footer, you have a some problems.

Comment: A new error appeared:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /home/masterli/public_html/application/admin/models/Mpages.php on line 532

Comment: add full code file or new code on line 532, i dont know, whats this in this line.